Problemas com a validação no Spring Boot
Olá, estou encontrando alguns problemas com a validação no SpringBoot, mais especificamente na validação de parâmetros dos métodos.
Estou utilizando a versão 3.2.5 do Spring Boot e a 17 do Java.
Minhas dependências são essas:
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>annotationProcessor</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0-M2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

O problema persiste com e sem a jakarta.validation-api.
// Estou fazendo as importações da dependência jakarta.validation, pois a antiga javax.validation foi descontinuada na atual versão do SpringBoot.

import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Validated
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class BooksController {

// Essas validações NÃO estão funcionando.
@PostMapping("/book")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getBookByName(@RequestBody @NotNull @NotBlank @NotEmpty String name) {

        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

// Essas validações estão funcionando.
@PostMapping("/newbook")
    public ResponseEntity<Book> saveBook(@RequestBody @Valid Book book) {
        Book newBook = bookService.saveBook(book);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(newBook);
    }

}

Estou errando em algo ou é um bug ? Desde já agradeço.

Acredito que a maneira correta de fazer as validações é através de um objeto, você pode criar um DTO(Data Transfer Object) para essa finalidade, por exemplo:
Em vez de usar uma String diretamente como parâmetro do método, crie um DTO com um campo name e anote esse campo com as validações desejadas.
public class GetBookRequestDTO {
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    // Getters e Setters...
}

@PostMapping("/book")
public ResponseEntity<?> getBookByName(@RequestBody @Valid GetBookRequestDTO request) {
    String name = request.getName();
    
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}

Quando você coloca @Valid em um parâmetro de método de um controlador Spring, você está dizendo ao Spring para validar o objeto que está sendo passado como corpo da solicitação (neste caso, GetBookRequestDTO) usando as anotações de validação presentes nas suas classes.
Uma pequena observação: é bom analisar a necessidade de usar essas 3 anotações, pois pode ser um pouco redundante, mas vai depender do contexto da sua aplicação.
Espero ter ajudado, abraços !

Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas na Central de Ajuda.
